# Extract exact match of predefined phrases in array from string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

Need `$new_string` to output `New York NY` but am getting `New York NY York NY`

```
$phrases = array("New York NY","York NY","Wyoming MI","Wyoming Minnesota");
$string = ("I live in New York NY");

$matches = array();
foreach($phrases as $phrase) {
    if(stripos($string,$phrase) !== false){
        $matches[] = $phrase;
    }
}

$new_string = implode(" ",$matches);

echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `stripos("I live in New York NY", "New York NY")` and `stripos("I live in New York NY", "York NY")` is `!=== false`

You can create a loop that only favors the longer text

```
$phrases = array("New York NY","York NY","Wyoming MI","Wyoming Minnesota");
$string = ("I live in Wyoming Minnesota");
$matches = array();
foreach ( $phrases as $phrase ) {
    $phrase = preg_quote($phrase, '/');
    if (preg_match("/\b$phrase\b/i", $string)) {
        $matches[] = $phrase;
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Wyoming Minnesota
)
```

preg_match / If the optional delimiter  [@DaveRandom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889949/daverandom)

Comment: This works for "I live in New York NY", "I live in York NY", "I live in Wyoming MI" but fails for "I live in Wyoming Minnesota"

Comment: Thanks for your help. Updated code works for "I live in Wyoming Minnesota" now, but fails for "I live in New York NY".  You helped me get on the right track, hopefully I can figure it out from here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by it fails ... works perfectly from here http://eval.in/2889

Comment: When you add another value to $phrases such as "10016" and to $string such as "I live in New York NY 10016" it adds "York NY" to $matches

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's looking to see if any `$phrase` is found in your `$string`.

Both `New York NY` and `York NY` are found in `$string`, so they're both added to `$matches`.

---

I'm not sure what the "big picture" is, but you may want to split `$string` into two parts, then compare the locations only:

```
$places = array("New York NY","York NY","Wyoming MI","Wyoming Minnesota");
$strLive = "I live in ";
$strLoc = "New York NY";

$matches = array();
foreach($places as $place) {
    if($strLoc == $place){
        $matches[] = $place;
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to extract predefined US location phrases from a single-line input field.